# Overwrite Bootstrap Display:Inline property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using bootstrap Tabs css.

I am trying to make the tabs vertical rather than horizontal(default by bootstrap).

I tried overwriting "display:inline,inline-block" property provided by bootstrap for nav-tabs by creating a user css, that is loaded AFTER bootstrap, with a "display:block" property for the ul.

It still refuses to budge and is still horizontal.

Any ideas? I am looking for a css only solution.

Comment: I know this is not what you asked, but have you considered using Bootstrap's own native solution for vertical tabs? Check out "Stacked tabs", "Tabs on the left" and "Tabs on the right" on this page. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

Comment: i must be blind to not notice that. Thank you.

Comment: i would still like to know if there is an answer to my question though.

Comment: Are you looking at an older version of the bootstrap? The tabs are `display:block` by default and just floated to the left.

Comment: no. I'm using the latest version. Thats the nav-tabs class i'm talking about